# confusion matrix: 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'

Tags: r

I am trying to validate the accuracy of my model and I want a confusion matrix.

The first 5 rows of the data look like this:

```
Regio            verschil    rangschikking          nieuwerangschikking  categorie                   gespeeld  percentgewonnen   absolutepunten  relatievepunten  huidigelo
Vlaams-Brabant   0           Rangschikking : C6     Rangschikking : C6   Categorie : Veteranen 40    66        0.5000            297             -2               1412
Vlaams-Brabant   0           Rangschikking : C4     Rangschikking : C4   Categorie : Veteranen 50    81        0.6790            509             -16              1462
Vlaams-Brabant   -1          Rangschikking : C4     Rangschikking : C6   Categorie : Veteranen 50    69        0.4493            265             -40              1355
Luxemburg        0           Rangschikking : E6     Rangschikking : E6   Categorie : Seniors Heren   4         0.5000            2               -4                318
Waals-Brabant    2           Rangschikking : E0     Rangschikking : E2   Categorie : Veteranen D 50  44        0.4091            62              -23               695
```

The code I am using is:

```
model <- clm(verschil ~., data = pingpong2)
fitted.results <- predict(model,newdata=subset(test),type="class")
confusionMatrix(data=fitted.results, reference=test$verschil)
```

The confusionmatrix gives the following error:

```
Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?
```

I get the fitted.results, so I can actually see the predictions, but why does the confusionmatrix not work?

Comment: `fitted.results` is probably a data frame rather than a vector. It should be something like `data=fitted.results$fit`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. But it works, thanks!